# Redirect mail from system user account to real email account

Tags: linux, email, postfix, users

First, I would like to thank you for your time.

I've come to the following situation:

- I've got a mail server named `mx1.domain.com`
- This mail server is virtual hosting some domains mail accounts like `user1@somedomain.org`, `user1@someotherdomain.net`
- As long as the hostname for the server is (and should be so the `SMTP Banner` is the same hostname as the IP rdl to) `mx1.domain.com` the default Postfix accounts and server accounts `postmaster@mx1.domain.com hostmaster@mx1.domain.com ...` are binded to the real hostname, not virtuals.
- I've got a simple user for login through ssh, and I've set up my /etc/aliases so the email for all those 'default' addresses go to `root` user and then I set up `root` mail to get into my `login` user instead.

How can I get all those emails, that my system and users send to those default addresses on a real email account? Like one of those that I virtual host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume, that POSTFIX is your local MTA. Thus the following should solve your problem:

```
echo "yourdestination@domain.com" > $HOME/.forward
```

(http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html)

Comment: This supposes that the addresses correspond to actual local accounts - which does not seem to be the case, since the poster mentiones virtually hosted domains.

Comment: no... you can use any email address in the .forward file. just like someaccount@gmail.com - i used this many times in the past.

Comment: You misunderstand me. The address where the .forward file lives must be a local account on the server.

Comment: maybe i did... but i read the OPs question in the way that he wants exactly that: to have the local account's email forwarded to a virtual mailbox :)

Comment: Yep Wolfie is right, Maybe next time I'll make shorter questions.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix has a feature to connect a virtual domain to a particular user. It's described in [the virtual readme](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html). Here's a short step-by-step guide:

Add the following lines to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_domains = example.com second.example.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Edit `/etc/postfix/virtual` and add a mapping for each domain to a username

```
# one address in example.com goes to a specific address
postmaster@example.com   postmaster
# all other addresses in example.com go to oneuser
@example.com             oneuser
# all addresses in second.example.com go to seconduser
@second.example.com      seconduser
```

Once you've finished this, do the following:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postfix reload
```

Whenever you  add a domain or change a forwarding, just `/etc/postfix/virtual` and do `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` again.

Comment: I'm sorry that maybe I didn't explained well, so You've interpreted my question backwards, Wolfie's hint is doing great what I wanted.